# How to transfer a Base64 string from vanilla Javascript to node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, base64

I have some code(vanilla Javascript) that allows me to generate a Base64 string from an image and it works. I have to bring this string to node js and then store it in a MongoDB database. The problem is that once the fetch is done the string is undefined. What can I do?

Base64 encoder

```
    var logoUri;
    const file = logo.files[0];
    if(file.size<=2e+6){
        const reader = new FileReader
    reader.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
        // console.log(reader.result)
        logoUri=reader.result
        console.log(logoUri) // the console log works
//then i fetch (post) this logoUri
    })
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
```

Comment: You should probably make a POST request with the base64 string in the body.

Comment: That's what I've done

Comment: Do you the result on the server, in the endpoint handler?